# Как в AWS организовать связку (на 2 инстансах EC2) MongoDB + Веб-сервер?

Tags: mongodb

Есть 2 EC2 c3.xlarge на одном хочу разместить MongoDB на другом Webserver(Apache+PHP).
Как в AWS организовать работу инстанса с Webserver с инстансом MongoDB с минимальными задержками?

А проще говоря как сделать чтобы инстанс с MongoDB был не открыт для мира но при этом инстанс с вебсервером его видел?

Answer (score 1):

Очевидным вариантом взаимодействия двух инстансов является сетевое взаимодействие. Т.е. на сервере с Веб вы указываете адрес подключения к серверу с БД.

ЕС2 амазона позволяет объеденить инстансы в виртуальную сеть [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/details/). В этой сети ваши инстансы будут обмениваться данными с повышенной скоростью и без выхода в интернет.

Для защиты от доступа из вне, не зависимо от использования VPC, вам необходимо настроить фаервол в панели управления ЕС2 инстанс. 
На инстансе с БД добавьте разрешение на входащее соединение к монго (порт 27017) только с адреса второго инстанса.